# Solve $\frac{dy}{dt}=By$ where B is a matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

## Given B=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 &  0 \\
    0     & 2 & -3 \\
  0      & 3 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

Solve $\frac{d\textbf{y}}{dt}=B\textbf{y}$

If B was Diagonal matrix it would be piece of cake but now I got this three equations

$\frac{dy_1}{dt}=y_1$

$\frac{dy_2}{dt}=2y_2-3y_3$

$\frac{dy_3}{dt}=3y_2+2y_3$

While I can solve the first one by just splitting the variables, I don't know how to solve the other two:

$y_1=Aexp(t)$

$y_2=?$, $y_3=?$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf y' = B\mathbf y\\
\mathbf y = e^{Bt}\mathbf y(0)$

$e^{Bt} = \sum \frac {B^nt^n}{n!}$

If $B = P^{-1}DP$
then $B^n = P^{-1}D^nP$

$e^{Bt} = P^{-1} e^{Dt} P\\
e^{Dt} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1 t}\\&e^{\lambda_2 t}\\&&e^{\lambda_3 t}\end{bmatrix}$

Sometimes it is easier to work with:

$P\mathbf y = e^{Bt}(P\mathbf y(0))$

$y_1 = C_1 e^t\\
y_2 = C_2 e^{2t}\cos 3t +  C_3 e^{2t}\sin 3t\\
y_3 = C_3 e^{2t}\cos 3t -  C_2 e^{2t}\sin 3t$

Alternatively:

$y_2' = 2y_2 - 3y_3\\
y_2'' = 2y_2' - 3y_3'\\
y_2'' = 2(2y_2 - 3y_3) - 3(3y_2 + 2y_3)\\
y_2'' = -5 y_2 - 12 y_3\\
y_3  = \frac 13(2y_2-y_2')\\
y_2'' = -5y_2 - 8y_2 + 4y_2'\\
y_2'' - 4y_2' + 13y_2 = 0$

and that is a 2nd order diff eq you should know how to solve

Comment: Do you have to find P and D? Becasue B clearly has complex eigenvalues and hence eigenvectors, therefore I wasn't convinced with using this method

Comment: You don't really need to find P, especially if you have not been given initial conditions.  Complex eigenvalues, lead to trig functions upon exponentiation.  Since $e^{it} = \cos t + i\sin t$.  So, all you really need is the characteristic function $(\lambda - 1)(\lambda -2 + 3i)(\lambda - 2 - 3i)$ and you can guess the rest.

Comment: in that case one more thing to clarify. In second line of your work you are saying $y=exp(Bt)y(0)$ but now you are telling me to just do $y=exp(Dt)y(0)$. That is the one thing I don't really understand

EDIT: Don't mind me ! exp(Dt) is a diagonal matrix for exp(Bt). Thank You for the help sir.!

Comment: Using laplace Transform would give you half of the pain!

Comment: I haven't been clear. I was addressing the "alternate way". For the solution using exponential matrix, hand computation of matrix $P$ **and** of its inverse takes more than two minutes; it is more or less as time consuming as separation into partial fractions. See the solution I give.

Answer (score 0):

For a hand calculation, using Laplace Transform (LT) is an alternative.

(thanks to @Doug M for the spotting of a computational error).

Let $a=y_1(0), b=y_2(0), c=y_3(0).$

Let us make a separate treatment of the LT of the first equation on one hand, and the second and third on the other hand.

- $sY_1-a=Y_1 \ \iff \ Y_1=\dfrac{a}{s-1} \ \iff \ y_1(t)=ae^{t}$
- $\begin{cases}sY_2-b&=&2Y_2-3Y_3\\sY_2-c&=&3Y_2+2Y_3\end{cases} \ \iff \ \begin{cases}(2-s)Y_2-3Y_3&=&-b\\3Y_2+(2-s)Y_3&=& \ \ c\end{cases} $

Solving this parametric system by Cramer (determinant) method, with $\Delta=(s-2)^2+3^2$, one obtains:

$$\begin{cases}Y_2&=&\dfrac{b(s-2)+3c}{(s-2)^2+3^2}\\Y_3&=&\dfrac{-c(s-2)+3b}{(s-2)^2+3^2}
\end{cases},$$

from which it is immediate to obtain, using a table of LT, the result.

$$\begin{cases}y_2(t)&=&e^{2t}(b\cos(3t)+c\sin(3t))\\y_3(t)&=&e^{2t}(-c\cos(3t)-b\sin(3t))
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $(2-s)^2 - 3^2 = s^2 - 4s + 13 \ne (s+1)(s+5)$  And, yes, I had this wrong on my "alternative solution" as well.  I flipped a sign near the beginning.  Should have stuck with the matrix aproach.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much! Next time, as you say, I will use matrix method:):):)